# Problem Using Resistors in LTSpice

Tags: resistors, ltspice

I am new to electrical engineering and I’m having a lot of issues with resistance in LTSpice.

Because I can’t set the current, I am unable to determine how far the voltage will drop.

For example, I have a resistor (R) connected to a voltage source (12V), and I want to make the voltage 5V for an LED. The problem is I cannot calculate the resistance because I don’t know what the current will be.

How do I find out what the current will be? Or better yet, how am I supposed to use resistors in general? I’ve taken a look at a lot of explanations, but they all have the resistance ready, so I don’t know how they get to that value.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: I think your problem may be in the line "I want to make the voltage 5V for an LED", LED's don't work like that, you don't work out what voltage you want them to drop and then pop in a resistor to make that happen. They have a pre-defined voltage drop, about 2v typical for a red LED. After 'turning on' any further voltage just starts to push as much current as the supply can give it, quickly destroying the LED. We pick a resistor to limit current, the resistor will drop the rest of the supply voltage, and this is what you use to work out the value to get the current you need (20mA typical).

Comment: I just checked and my LTSpice default LED drops about 750mA at 12v with a 350Ω resistor. This will go up and down a BIT depending on the current it's passing, but not at all in the linear way that you would see if you replaced the LED with a resistor. This model of an LED will drop roughly 750mA from when it lights up to when it is destroyed.

Comment: I might not have gotten my point across properly but I meant that the input to the LED would be 5V, and then I rechecked the data sheet and saw it was 3.0-3.2V, 20mA. I do know that diodes have a certain voltage drop, but I was referring to the resistor, as I couldn’t figure out how to use resistors in a simple circuit to limit the current going into the LED. I’m still getting familiar with the names and components, so my apologies if it doesn’t make sense. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an LED model that you don't understand you can probe it by putting a fixed current through it and 'measuring' the voltage by simulation.

For example, if I have a Nichia NSCW100 model I can do this:

[image]

The voltage across this particular LED is 3.64523V at 20mA (to a ridiculous number of decimal places, really), so I calculate the resistor value to be about 417.7 ohms, and as you can see in the right-hand circuit it works out very closely (much more closely than the model of the LED, resistor and power source will likely match cold hard reality).

Note that 5V is a very high forward voltage for an LED that is not being abused, more like the typical rating for maximum reverse voltage. It's *possible* for a UV LED but they are rather exotic parts. It's also unlikely to be exactly 5.0V.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, You take the voltage source voltage. Subtract the forward voltage drop of the LED from the voltage source. That leaves you with the remaining voltage that gets dropped across the resistor. Using ohm's Law, the current in the whole circuit is the remaining voltage divided by the resistor value.

Normally, you're going to want to set the resistor AFTER you determine the current required. So in this case, take the voltage that would be dropped across the resistor and divide that by your required current to get the proper resistor value.

Comment: This is what I’ve been trying to do, but every time I do it this way, I get a higher and higher value in LTspice. This is what I’ve been doing: The LED would have a forward voltage of 5V at 0.02 Amps (20mA). So, I take the voltage that has to be dropped (7V) and divide it by 0.02. Once I put R back into the circuit, instead of giving me 20mA it gives me a value like 34mA.

Comment: It should be 350 ohms. What does: "...I put R back into the circuit" mean? Leave R in the circuit.

Comment: 5V lost to the LED. 7V across the resistor. You want 20mA, so 7V/20mA amounts to 350 ohms.

Comment: It means I put 350 ohms in the circuit, and it gave me a random mA value.

Comment: So what's the voltage across the resistor (probe it in the simulation)? In other words, what's the voltage at the LED-resistor node WRT ground (V-)?

Comment: My guess is the LED model is incorrect; I bet it's not "really" 5V. Post a screenshot in your question for additional commentary.

Answer (score 1):

First off, choose a device for the LED. I picked a model at random that was in LTSpice's model library (right-click on D1). You will need to supply a model for the LED you are actually using.

Download the specification sheet for the LED. In the particular spec sheet for the Nichia NSPW500BS, a graph of forward voltage drop versus LED current is shown below. Let's choose a LED current of 20 mA. At 20 mA the forward voltage across the LED is approximately 3.6 volts. This means the voltage across R1 must be \$12 - 3.6 = 8.4 V\$.

Thus, the resistor value is \$ R = {E \over I} = {8.4 \over 0.02} = 420 \;ohms\$.

The SPICE simulation using the.op statement shows that the LED current is 20.7 mA which is close to the calculated value. The difference in the calculated versus simulated currents is the difference between the specification sheet and the model's forward drop. Note that the simulation is predicting a 3.3 V drop across the diode.

In practice, you would measure the voltage drop across the diode for the specified conditions and lot variations.

[image]